# How do I check a buffer for words from a list?

Tags: highlight

I'm wondering how to:

- Check the presence in the current buffer of words that are present in a given file and
- Highlight them.

Comment: Plugin requests are off-topic; an answer might include "try this plugin [details]," but we prefer the question to be plugin agnostic to not exclude non-plugin answers.

Comment: Is one of the answers addressing your problem? How can we help you further?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I commented one answer to get further help. Thank you for asking.

Comment: If the solution fit your need maybe could you validate it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing you want to highlight the word list with the `WarningMsg` highlighting group (you can change that).

Here what I would do:

```
execute 'match' 'WarningMsg' '/\V' .. join(readfile(path_to_file), '\|') .. '/'
```

**Explanation**

The `match` command: `match` *highlighting_group* `/`*pattern*`/` highlight the string that match the *pattern* with the *highlighting_group*

The code is building the command  as a string and execute it with the `execute` command.

The `readfile` read the line of the file and return a list (e.g. ['foo', 'bar'])

The `join` function convert the list into a string using the `\|` separator (e.g. `foo\|bar`) searching for all the words (e.g. either `foo` or `bar`)

Because the words could contains special character that have pattern meaning (e.g. `.`) we prefix the pattern with `\V` to match as literally as possible with Vim.

More information in the doc with `:help match`, `:help readfile()`, `:help join()`, `:help /\V`.

**Using a Command**

You can also create a `Highlight` command for it:

```
command! -narg=1 -complete=file Highlight execute 'match' 'WarningMsg' '/\V' .. join(readfile(<f-args>), '\|') .. '/'
```

The `command` command introduce a new command:

- `-narg=1` set the number of argument to the command to 1
- `--complete=file` tell Vim that the argument is a file and the file autocompletion could be used.
- `<f-args>` is the list of argument quoted

More information with `:help command`,`:help command-nargs`, `:help command-complete` and `:help <f-args>`

**Supporting words with Backslash**

```
command! -narg=1 -complete=file Highlight execute 'match' 'WarningMsg' '/\V' .. join(mapnew(readfile(<f-args>), {_, v -> escape(v, '\')}), '\|') .. '/'
```

Remark: The `mapnew` code escape each word of the list it takes the list of the words and a lambda function that get the index of the element in the list (`_`) and the element itself (`v`) and return the replacement `escape(v, '\')`/

More information with: `:help mapnew()`, `:help lambda`

Thanks to @Ben for that.

**Stop Higlighting**

To stop highlighting you can do:

```
match none
```

Or if you prefer (as suggested by @romainl) to extend the highlighting with the command you could do:

```
command! -narg=1 -complete=file Highlight call matchadd('WarningMsg', '\V' .. join(readfile(<f-args>)))
```

But the code to reset the highlighting is slightly more complex to write

Comment: I was about to post a very similar answer, but using `:help matchadd()` instead of `:help :match`.

Comment: Wow, thanks. Since I'm new to this: please explain, where do I have to use your lines of code. I copied one line in the .vimrc (edited the path to the words.txt) but it didn't work. Seems I used your code not in the way I'd have to.

Comment: I have added some explanation. Don't hesitate to ask me for more.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Thanks for the explanation. I'm still wondering where to put your code. In the .vimrc? Or in a *.vim-file as a plugin? Sorry to ask again, but I'm still a novice.

Comment: You are more than welcome :-) The `.vimrc` is a very standard place to put it.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Thank you, very much!

Comment: It's not that much more effort to make use of `matchadd()`. In fact I find it much more flexible. Simply run `matchdelete()` with the ID returned by `matchadd()` function. In fact, I would no longer recommend to use the `:match` command any more

Comment: @Christian, you are right but we have then to store the list of IDs in a buffer variable that we could use the delete the match (not a lot of work but somehow more complex).

Answer (score 2):

Let's use `LogiPat` to build a search pattern for all words in the file:

```
const words = readfile('words')
const patterns = mapnew(words, {_, v -> printf('"%s"', substitute(v, '"', '&&', 'g'))})
const logipat = join(patterns, '|')
execute 'LogiPat' logipat
```

or all together

```
execute 'LogiPat' readfile('words')->mapnew({_,v -> printf('"%s"', substitute(v, '"', '&&', 'g'))})->join('|')
```

With `set hlsearch`, this highlights everything. And `n`/`N` navigate matches.

Now, `LogiPat` highlights whole lines because it uses `.*` around each pattern. You could also try

```
const words = readfile('words')
const patterns = mapnew(words, {_, v -> printf('\(%s\)', escape(v, '\'))})
const pat = join(patterns, '\|')
execute 'normal! /`..pat.."\<Enter>"
```

where `\V` and `escape(v, '\')` help us build robust patterns for literal text.